# Pasar variable int a string

Tags: php, laravel

perdón la pregunta que hare, pero he intentado pasar una varible numerica a string, pero no me toma resulta.  Por ejemplo en mi base de datos tengo un campo llamado "plano" tipo varchar y necesito que guarde de esta manera 088, pero cuando imprimo la varible solo me toma 88, mi pedacito de codigo es asi

```
$nw="0";  
$codigo=$nw."".$plano[0]->plano;
```

Debo poner algo que me falte, para que me tome el 0 que necesito y me guarde 088 y no 88.

Gracias

Comment: Ese código que publicas en que momento lo usas? para mostrar lo que viene de la bd o para guardar?

Comment: Para guardar el nuevo registro y me tome el 0

Comment: agrega a la pregunta el código que usas para insertar (sentencia sql completa)

Comment: Trabajo con Laravel, y creo que con esas 2 líneas de código debería registrar el plano como lo necesito, ya que $nw=0, y después concateno el $nw."".$plano[0]->plano;  y la variable que inserto en bdd es $codigo.  Con laravel no necesito escribir el tipico insert into, sino que llamo a la tabla y sus campos con la varibles

Comment: comprendo, probaste usar el $cast de laravel?? en tu modelo debes declarar:  protected $casts = [ 'plano' => 'string' ];  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: No lo he utilizado, pero disculpa mi ignorancia, para que me acepte el valor 0 necesito como primer digito necesito eso, ya que ahora me entrega como dato 88 y yo necesito que guarde 088

Comment: Entiendo lo que tú quieres, pero entonces prueba declarar la propiedad `protected $casts = [ 'plano' => 'string' ];` en tu  modelo para forzar el tipo de datos del atributo plano, es lo que se me ocurre..

Comment: lo otro, no queda claro en tu pregunta si en tu bd se guarda 88 o 088?? sólo tienes problemas para visualizar el dato en tus vistas o también tienes el problema para guardarlo???

Comment: ¿Y por qué mejor no formateas el dato en vez de convertirlo a string?

Comment: actualmente se guarda 88 y necesito que guarde 088, el 0 no me lo toma para guardarlo

Comment: Y por qué mejor no formateas el dato en vez de convertirlo a string?, COMO HAGO ESTO?

Comment: disculpa que insista, pero probaste declarando la propiedad? dime si te sirve o no para descartar esa opción, la ventaja de hacerlo es que ese atributo siempre será tratado como string en donde lo uses.. no tienes para que estar formateandolo siempre ej. `$codigo=(string)$nw."".$plano[0]->plano;`

Comment: Muchas gracias varTob, me ayudo lo que me dijiste

Comment: Impecable, qué te sirvió? forzar el tipo usando el (string) o definiste la propiedad $cast (que hace lo mismo)?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es agregar ceros a la izquierda puede usar la función **str_pad()**:

```
<?php
  $input = 88;
  echo str_pad($input, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);  // produce "088"
  echo str_pad($input, 3, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);   // produce "880"
?>
```

O también puedes hacer que se guarde con el cero adelante debido a que tu campo en la base de datos en **VARCHAR**. Y al momento de imprimirlo debe mostrarse igual "088"

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Jimmy